# Convert JsonString to Json Object

Tags: java, android, json

There Are Two Activities, Activity A & Activity B

I Made an API Call in activity A And converted the JsonObject into string for my further Use now I need to Send That JsonObject To Activity B and I Used **Intent.putExtra** for that so for sending I converted it to String while sending, Now I Need to Again Convert it to JsonObject for a post request but I'm Unable to do So.

Or You Can Tell me an easy way to send the JsonObject As it is to Activity B Without Converting it to String.

Here is the sample of JsonObject

```
{
    "data": {
        "care_of": "S/O: Kaleen Bhaiya",
        "full_name": "Munna Bhaiya",
        "aadhaar_number": "123456789011",
        "zip": "110088",
        "gender": "M",
        "share_code": "6921",
        "face_score": -1,
        "raw_xml": "https://link-to-docs",
        "has_image": true,
        "address": {
            "loc": "Lehna Singh Market",
            "street": "",
            "house": "Flat No - 123",
            "po": "Mirzapur",
            "country": "India",
            "subdist": "Mirzapur",
            "vtc": "Mirzapur",
            "dist": "North Mirzapur",
            "state": "Uttar Pradesh"
        },
        "client_id": "aadhaar_v2_JlgixCkkkqinfMqtnThX",
        "zip_data": "https://link-to-zip",
        "profile_image": "base_64_image",
        "face_status": false,
        "dob": "1996-01-01"
    },
    "success": true,
    "message_code": "success",
    "status_code": 200,
    "message": null
}
```

Your Help Is Much Appreciated

Comment: What json library are you using? builtin, gson, json.simple?

Comment: @Darkman I'm using gson library

Comment: Can you try JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myObj)

Comment: Thanks you for your response, I Have already tried That but still doesn't work !!

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse(yourJSONString);`

You can use JSON.parse() method for string to object co

Comment: Doesn't work there is no method **.parse()**

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library (by Google) for Serialization/Deserialization . You can find a nice guide [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-serialize-deserialize-json/).

Assuming your POJO called `Data`, it's going to be something like this:

**Serialization - Convert object to json string**

```
Data data = <your_object>;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(data);
```

**Desirialization - convert json string to object**

```
String dataJsonString = "<your_object_json_string>";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Data data = gson.fromJson(dataJsonString, Data.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case,we do not need to convert  json object to/from jsonString.
You can simply pass jsonObject to activity B from activity A as

```
intent.putExtra("jsonObject", YourJSonObject);
```

and recieve it on activity B as

```
YourJSonObject  yourjsonobject = (YourJSonObject)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("jsonObject");
```